# No abre http://localhost Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, asp.net

En visual studio 2015 creo una web y lo ejecuto sin que haya puesto algún codigo me sale esto en el navegador:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Codebing:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Pierro: esta pregunta es demasiado genérica y me sorprende en un usuario avezado como tú :) Dale a [edit] y añade detalles jugosos para que podamos echarle mano.

Comment: Si estás usando Boilerplate, comprueba que has definido la página de inicio. Si continuas con el problema, proporciónanos algo más de información para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Tiene pinta de que estas iniciando el proyecto con tu WebForm seleccionado directamente. Prueba a iniciar la web directamente con el index y desde ahí navegar hasta tu WebForm

Comment: @fedorqui listo ya puse los codigos. espero que me puedan ayudar.

Comment: @Pierro, cuando ejecutas la solución "F5" en la barra de tareas no se inicia el webServer en ejecución? mira esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12369779/4092887).